# How to customize a front page variant with CSS

Tags: 6, theming

I need to do some customization on a page variant front page of a section of a website. What is the best way to do this? I am working on Drupal 6 if that helps.

Comment: What kind of customizations do you need to do? You just want to find the css selector that will target the front page?

Comment: The site is using a node variant as a homepage. When viewing the code, the body does not have an ID for me to manipulate.

`<body class="not-front not-logged-in page-node node-type-page no-sidebars">`

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to give a panel page it's own ID so that I can add styles and manipulate the page without giving it a new theme. I am not on a multisite installation.